# How can I cause Fedora Linux to show me the GUI login screen?

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, gnome, kde

When I boot Fedora 19, the GUI does not start. I can start it manually, with startx, but this does not unlock my keyring, which is annoying.

This problem started when I tried to move from GNOME to KDE and tried to install KDE and uninstall GNOME, which did not work.

I guess I would like to reinstall GNOME from scratch if I could do so without loss of data.

Comment: What are you currently using, kdm, gdm, lightdm...?

Comment: I am using GDM right now

Comment: what does `runlevel` return? What about `grep initdefault /etc/inittab` In most Linuxes, you start gdm at runlevel 5. Not sure if latter Fedoras change this convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fedora uses, like Arch, the new systemd, so you should be able to start gdm at boot like this:

```
 sudo systemctl enable gdm
```

I hope this solves your problem, in light of your vicissitudes.

Comment: +1 .... mostly for (properly) using vicissitudes

Comment: That fails with "no such file or directory"

Comment: This will not work if system target is not graphical (`systemctl set-default graphical.target`) and if all GUI related packages are not installed (`dnf groupinstall "Fedora Workstation"`).

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo systemctl enable gdm.service
```

and maybe

```
sudo yum install "@Gnome Desktop"
```